# Is there a limit for the number of simultaneous async 'urlfetch'es issued in a request in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I did not find the answer in documentation and I see inconsistent answers [to this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639855/what-happens-if-an-application-calls-more-than-10-asynchronous-url-fetch-on-goog), so I wonder if there is an actual limit for the number of urlfetches running in parallel inside a request in google app engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there still is no such limit mentioned in the documentation and/or apparent in the SDK code.

But you could actually perform the few tests pretty documented in that fairly old question you referenced to gauge the actual status today.

Note: I'd highly recommend performing the tests in app code actually deployed on GAE, not running locally through the SDK - there may be behavioural differences which may skew the test results significantly. See, for example, [FetchOptions withLimit() does not reduce query execution time (Google App Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299070/fetchoptions-withlimit-does-not-reduce-query-execution-time-google-app-engine/47300181#47300181) (thought that's in respect to performance of the datastore, not urlfetch).

Comment: I ran 20 parallel calls through the admin console; worked. Per google cloud support there used to be a limitation of 10, but not any more.